# SQL query add only posts with custom field to array

Tags: array, sql

I have this SQL query which is building an array of wordpress posts...

```
$query = "select $wpdb->posts.* from $wpdb->posts,$wpdb->terms,$wpdb->term_taxonomy,$wpdb->term_relationships where $wpdb->terms.term_id in (".$catId.") and $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id and $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'pcategory' and $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' and $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id = $wpdb->posts.ID and $wpdb->posts.ID != ".$post->ID." group by $wpdb->posts.ID order by $wpdb->posts.ID LIMIT 0 ,$limit";
```

I need to modify this to allow me to add a condition that only posts with a specific custom field value, say 'Apple' are included in the array.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

### UPDATE

I have tried to modify it to this....

```
$query = "select $wpdb->posts.* from $wpdb->posts,$wpdb->terms,$wpdb->term_taxonomy,$wpdb->term_relationships where $wpdb->terms.term_id in (".$catId.") and $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id and $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'pcategory' and $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' and $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'fruit' and $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value= 'apple' and $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id = $wpdb->posts.ID and $wpdb->posts.ID != ".$post->ID." group by $wpdb->posts.ID order by $wpdb->posts.ID LIMIT 0 ,$limit";
```

I was assuming that this would narrow down the search to only the posts that have a value of 'apple' for the custom field named 'fruit' but its not working

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do:

```
<?php 
global $post;
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' = 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'fruit',
            'value' => 'apple'
        )
    )
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $custom_query->have_posts() ): $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```